# How to transform a conditional type to a different conditional type from values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to transform a conditional type into a different conditional type based on "values" (JS variables, not types per-se) or perhaps in a combination with the related generic type. I could possibly remove one of the types so I wouldn't need to do the transformation, however I'm looking to see if this way is possible.

It might come down to expressing `Payload extends void ? { ... } : { ... };` based on values/variables without using `as` or a different TS escape-hatch. I don't know if it's possible.

[See TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDCBXAzlAewFtMCIEwBzdAbwF9RQYAPABwLinSgE9WMACkh4AbAkgAmAdTBQAFgFkYUJAB4ho8RIB86ALzoNYyehawIE3OgBuBMBNABIAPxY8hEmQqUnALlrorMLGEv5GWuh06ABkbvjEpORUANyMILz86AByMADu4ZIAYhxESFDqwVq6BgUSpszmljZ2DiAuASheVP448Z5J1Axt-jSBlZJh4xLJ6J0DPe4JXYOpIKAA9OvocgS53ASzZNbwXLUy8koq%209l5tcVwpVDOoAjYEChQYGSHEMec8BVNJJtAAKIJA6SyRTKJCTCHnaEqQEhbQASlooHQ6E29SgcFQXDm3kxP3wP28%20nQIJB6L0uhoJKxYAQVIAROCQqz0JAxvCoZckOiGSAsaLSVxRhytAAadAAOgVRKokUpUskCIFqzFWLgymwcAg5OVSCsvQ8iW8WtFQzFuqg%20sNashFxhVroqJpqxJOJ2ewkB1yGCQrFYIh43DkGDmElkXwgSBE3D4MCsCDgxBsCewKeeIvQdodbKdXJ5To1MMZ6Fckqm-jL-JhcqdsqVg0rIyNbbz6PWACp0CabvkpvdHsiquhVABaCNgKxz-MwACO2DAurqBHk8Fyc4w8HTcHQva2uDKc4oKaHdxKZXHwNWQw2WzwSEoMFAczJutw2BEXAMcx-LAcAgsKWJOv4rK4MQGDFqA7qrEAA)

```js
interface CustomConfig {}

export type PayloadWithMeta<Payload> = Payload extends void
    ? CustomConfig
    : { payload: Payload } & CustomConfig;

type NewPayloadFormat<Payload> = Payload extends void
    ? { config: CustomConfig }
    : { payload: Payload; config: CustomConfig };

// how to convert PayloadWithMeta to NewPayloadFormat?
function converter<Payload>(payloadWithMeta: PayloadWithMeta<Payload>) {
  // extract config
  const config = (() => {
    if ("payload" in payloadWithMeta) {
      const { payload, ...config } = payloadWithMeta;
      return config as CustomConfig;
    }
    return payloadWithMeta;
  })();

  // how do we apply the conditional types from values?
  return ("payload" in payloadWithMeta
    ? { payload: payloadWithMeta.payload, config }
    : { config }
  ) /* as NewPayloadFormat<Payload> <- this is required otherwise error */ satisfies NewPayloadFormat<Payload>;
}

// usage
const result = converter({
  payload: "some payload"
});
```

Comment: What's going on with `extends void` here?  `void` is a *weird* type and is therefore distracting.  Maybe you could change it to `undefined` or something, unless your question depends strongly on using `void`?

Comment: (continued) TS really can't reason about generic conditional types.  If you want to avoid type assertions you could refactor your code substantially so that the conditional type is mostly a black box that gets reused, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDdDON). Does that fully address the question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think I used void so I was able to avoid having to pass an argument to a function in cases where not necessary, it's in a related part of the code. I don't exactly remember how it looked like though. Can try to find it next week

Comment: So then you don’t need it for this question (nothing stops you from  using `void` in your own code, of course), right?  … What are your thoughts about my suggested solution?

Comment: I have yet to implement it in our project but you definitely gave me inspiration and helped me steer the solution in the right direction. I may keep `extends void` in `PayloadWithMeta` but drop it in `NewPlayedFormat`, [draft solution](https://tsplay.dev/wXrrVm).

Comment: So if I write up my suggestion as an answer you’d be likely to accept? Or is there some issue that I haven’t accounted for?

Comment: Yeah, so the suggestion didn't really answer the question directly but rather side-stepped it - but as you mentioned my generic conditional types approach is hard for TS to reason about. So if you include that I'll accept it

Comment: The direct answer to your question is essentially "no you can't do this" (especially if type assertions or the like are precluded).  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance saying this and giving my suggestion as a workaround/alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript can't perform much useful reasoning about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, such as `PayloadWithMeta<P>` or `NewPayloadFormat<P>` inside the body of `converter()`.  Often the compiler will just treat a generic conditional type as *opaque*, and complain whenever you try to assign anything to it that isn't already known to be of that identical type.  If the type is just "equivalent" and not identical, the assignment will fail.  Or the compiler will decide to *prematurely evaluate* the type by widening generic type parameters to their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which might or might not throw away information you need.  Right now the compiler can't refine the type parameter inside a generic function enough to do anything "smart" with conditional types.  For now this is a general limitation of TypeScript.  Probably the most applicable open issue in GitHub is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), which talks specifically about a function being able to return a generic conditional type without [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

So, for now, if you want to keep your implementation as-is, you'll need to use type assertions or the like (e.g., single-call-signature [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)) and essentially abandon compiler-verified type safety.  That might be fine, as long as you understand that the role for verifying type safety has shifted to you.

---

If you want more compiler-verified type safety here, for this particular example, you could refactor to a version which keeps the generic conditional part as completely opaque the whole way through.  That is, write both `PayloadWithMeta<P>` and `NewPayloadFormat<P>` as a function of a common `Payload<P>` type that you just move around without trying to inspect.  Possibly like this:

```
type Payload<P> = P extends undefined ? { payload?: never } : { payload: P };
type PayloadWithMeta<P> = CustomConfig & Payload<P>;
type NewPayloadFormat<P> = { config: CustomConfig } & Payload<P>

function converter<P = undefined>(payloadWithMeta: PayloadWithMeta<P>): NewPayloadFormat<P> {
  const { payload, ...config } = payloadWithMeta;
  return { ...payloadWithMeta, config };
}
```

This works because inside the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in  `converter()`, `config` is seen as type `CustomConfig`, and `payload` is seen as type `Payload<P>`, whatever that is.  Then we [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `payloadWithMeta` back into a new object with a `config` property, which is represented as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  At no point does the compiler try to understand what's going on inside `Payload<P>`.

Anyway this refactoring might not always be possible for other examples, or might not be appropriate for a particular use case.  So the general answer here is unfortunately that, for generic conditional types, you're going to be smarter than the compiler and should use type assertions accordingly, at least as of TypeScript 5.0.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbVHEGYAc2QG9kAPALmWylHIF8BYAKE7AE8AHFAAU4PADY44AEwA8ggHzIAvMkHII1SCEmZk6LRBIgIk5AH5KyPiPFTT9IwDdoyFsnpUrYiZPqqWAbm5+IWtvAHVgMAALAFkIMDhZBWUMbHxCYjJkADIVUKkkwI5eAWQAOQgAd2EvKQAxHCg8ODAkpQsEIhJSelTcAi6s11yamxl5Tk4YPQQwYCJkTpAnKEgoWXa9SQNQYzkACk8xiOi4hN98yRPY+MT5AEp6CurLhqaWtopOZEWibAsjt4ADTIAB04KW3Rc7UBUmuZzgRR+UHi6CgIAs4NBsKukRuCRBkKGRXYXA4AHpybpMHBSBBOEt-ijMOhRGB2ksVmt9l8OD8cfQAESYfAoHGCoHfGhCwWcFj3IpAA)